# VB.NET - How to convert to If-else statement

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, file-io

I have a text file having the contents below and I want to convert it into an `If`-`Else` statement.

---

Text file contents:

```
11AM_3 = 0
|   11AM_1 = 1
|   |   4PM_1 = 3
|   |   |   4PM_2 = 0
|   |   |   |   11AM_2 = 0 : 0 (0/0)
|   |   |   |   11AM_2 = 2 : 3 (2/0)
|   |   4PM_2 = 3
|   |   |   4PM_3 = 0
|   |   |   |   11AM_2 = 3 : 1 (2/0)
|   11AM_1 = 2
|   |   4PM_1 = 9 : 1 (1/0)
```

---

Here is my code which can read the contents of the text file but I don't know how I can convert it into an If-else statement.

```
OpenFileDialog1.Multiselect = False
OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "TXT (*.txt)|*.txt"

If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then

    Dim pathoftextfile As String = OpenFileDialog1.FileName

    Dim sr as StreamReader = New StreamReader(pathoftextfile)

    Do while sr.peek>=0
         ' code here to read each line and convert into if-else

    Loop
    sr.close()
End if
```

---

The expected converted if-else statement of the text file should be like this.

```
If (11AM_3=0) then
    If(11AM_1=1) then
        If(4PM_1=3) then
            If(4PM_2=0) then
                If(11AM_2=0) then
                    return 0
                Elseif(11AM_2=2) then
                    return 3
                End if
            end if
        Elseif(4PM_2=3) then
            If(4PM_3=0) then
                If(11AM_2=3) then
                    return 1
                end if
            end if
        End if
    ElseIf(11AM_2=2) then
        If(4PM_1=9) then
            return 1
        end if
    end if
end if
```

---

What can I possibly use in reading each character in a line? Like in

> 11AM_3 = 0

I want to read the equals(=) so that I can print the start of the If statement which would be

```
If (11AM_3=0) then
```

with its corresponding 'End If' then the

> 11AM_1=1

which would be inside the 11AM_3 (e.g.)

```
If (11AM_3=0) then
    If(11AM_1=1) then
```

and the equals(=) and colon(:) symbols which is an indication that the value after the colon(:) will be returned like in

> 11AM_2 = 0 : 0

which is equal to

```
If (11AM_2 = 0) then
     return 0
End If
```

P.S. I want to output the converted `If`-`Else` statement to a new text file (output.txt).

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow, normally questions which just ask "how do I do this ?" without showing previous effort from your part, tend to be looked down upon. Can you edit your question to show what you have attempted, allowing people to correct your misunderstandings and point you in the right direction. Also if you have time please read through [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page of stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to convert a text file directly into compiled .NET code.

It seems like what you're asking is to read a text file, then have .NET create an if-then structure from that file.  There's simply no way to do that directly.  You would need some sort of interim structure to hold the logic via *probably* classes or a database.

I don't think you'll find someone willing to do all of that logic for you here.  Especially without knowing exactly how you're trying to structure things and what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thank you for notifying me and I'm sorry, I forgot to add up that the converted If-else will be stored in another text file.